# create local storage in angularjs across subdomains

Tags: angularjs, local-storage

how to create localstorage value from one domain and read from multiple sub domains.

for example : If i am logging in from abc.domain.com , how can i access that local storage from xyz.domain.com .

is there a way to create a localstorage in browser for *.domain.com, so that i can read that value from all subdomains of my site.

I have read online people are suggesting to create localstorage in parent domain and read in all subdomains with iframe concept: [Cross-Domain LocalStorage](https://jcubic.wordpress.com/2014/06/20/cross-domain-localstorage/).

i want to just create local for *.domainname.com

Answer (score 1):

you can use this :
https://github.com/ofirdagan/cross-domain-local-storage

maybe there is a simpler solution.